# Mecanim animation line up with in game logic?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unity3d-mecanim

In my top-down RPG, I have several enemies like Goblins, Trolls, Dragons,...

Each of them have two variables:

**baseAttackDuration** = float (how long in seconds does attack take, varies between enemies)
**increasedAttackSpeed** = float (attack speed modifier, may change during combat, also varies between enemies)

So when the character attacks, the duration of the attack equals to:
**attackDuration** = **baseAttackDuration** / **increasedAttackSpeed**

**Question:**
Now, how should I set Mecanim to play attack animation so the animation lines up with in game logic and lasts exactly attackDuration?

Comment: Not really an answer, but a suggestion: as far as I remember, you may set Animation's speed. Therefore, you could calculate a desired speed based on the regular animation length and on your desired animation length, so the animation would take exactly as long as you want. I did not try it myself, but this might work.

Comment: Unfortunately, Unity Mecanim system is a state machine where you cannot directly ask for animation clip of target state and therefore you cannot acquire animation length. You only can ask for duration of clip of a state that is currently active, but there are several more obstacles, for example when you switch to another state it wont update immediately, but in the next frame. I was kinda looking if someone has a clean way to handle this headache.

Comment: Use Animation Events to trigger game logic off of the animation.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html Then, set the animation speed to control how long it takes.

Comment: Can you bulk-add those? My plan is to have 30 enemy types, each having 10-20 animations.